# You're stronger than I am vs You're stronger than me

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, comparative-constructions

Those things are correct gramatically?
What's the difference?

My girlfriend and I went to the beach and I threw her in the water and she said

"You're stronger than I am."

I think that "You're stronger than me." is always correct gramatically..

Comment: @EddieKal  I agree it's a duplicate, but unfortunately the answer there presents as *definitely correct* something which is still *hotly debated*.  Many feel that the sentence "You are stronger than me" is perfectly grammatical.